# Enlarging the size of Facebook send button?

Tags: css, facebook, user-interface, facebook-social-plugins

**Is there a way of enlarging the Facebook send button by using css on it ?**

The small send button seems very miniature for the site am trying to build with its bigger font size

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS transforms](http://html5please.us/#transforms) like [scale, scaleX or scaleY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#scale) to change size of elements.

To get [Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) with size of 150% you may use something like:

```
.fb-send, fb\:send {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

[You may see this in action (without polyfill)](http://jsfiddle.net/SkuK8)

**Notes**:

- Remember about browser specific prefixes: `-webkit`, `-moz`, `-o` and `-ms`.
- Internet Explorer supports CSS transforms only from version 9, so you'll need to use [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) to support older versions.

**Update:**
Aside of using CSS for scaling the original button you may use [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) as suggested in other answer. Use [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) (using method `send` of [`FB.ui`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)) and your custom button that may look as you wish, just fire next code once clicking on custom button:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  name: document.title,
  link: document.location.href
});
```

Comment: Be aware that the Send Dialog is not supported for mobile!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The Send button is within an iFrame so you cannot change how it looks outside of the options provided [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/). I recommend using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) send dialog and building your own button (you can even take the CSS/Styles from FB if you like):

Comment: You can't style it, but nothing stops you from scaling it! See my answer. ;)